# Writing to an xml file C# WP7

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

The code is bellow...and I get the error at the last line : loadedData.Save("levelNo.xml");

And i don't understand why as there is a method with that type of parameter in XDocument : Save(String)     Serialize this XDocument to a file, overwriting an existing file, if it exists.

Errors i get:
  Error 2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Xml.XmlWriter'
  Error 1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.Xml.XmlWriter)' has some invalid arguments

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("levelNo.xml", LoadOptions.None);
        XElement root = loadedData.Root;
        XElement asset = (XElement)root.FirstNode;
        asset.RemoveAll();
        asset.Add(new XElement("level", levelNo));
        asset.Add(new XElement("mana", player.Mana));
        asset.Add(new XElement("score", score));

        loadedData.Save("levelNo.xml");
```

I really need some help...I've been searchig for some hours for a solution...My goal is to modify the levelNo.xml file, and then rewrite it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you hoping to save the file to? In Windows Phone 7 you need to use isolated storage. There's a [guide to WP7 Isolated Storage](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage) which has various examples, including reading and writing XML.

Ultimately, you'll need to open an [`IsolatedStorageFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx), then create an [`IsolatedStorageFileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.aspx), and write to that:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var stream = store.CreateFile("levelNo.xml"))
    {
        loadedData.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm thing is that i can easily read from an xml file, withouth using the isolated storage...Can't i do the same with writing?

Comment: @Teshte: Can you *really*? Have you actually got that working? Bear in mind that `XDocument.Load` can take a URI, which *does* make sense in WP7.

Comment: `code`using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create("levelNo.xml"))
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();

                reader.ReadToFollowing("level");
                int lvl = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadInnerXml()); `code`                                                               This is how i read...bear in mind that i added the file to the place where i have all the other classes...not good programming i know..but the thing with the isolated storage and the emulator..from what i read..is that once you close the emulator, those data are lost..

Comment: @Teshte: That will *compile*, sure... but does it *work*? Where does it read the data from? (And would you expect to be able to *write* to the same storage area?)

Comment: I did that because it made testing easier from me...and that is why i wanted to do the xml writing from the initial post...however..i will try to do the isolated storage thing like you said...Thanks :)